# Iterating over symbols in relation in Sympy

Tags: python-2.7, getter, sympy

I have a large list of equations randomly organized which I am running through and I would like to know how to find what variables are in any equation in the list. I am using relations [x**2-y) not Eq(x**2,y).

Is there a simple function like get_vars(expr) to dump out variable symbols individually into a list? Thanks for the help!

Comment: try `.atoms()` or `.free_symbols()`

Comment: Use `free_symbols`. `atoms` will give you something different.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the list?